# GCM with PHP Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: php, android

I am using GCM services to push information from server.
I try like this sample everything.
http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

I did everything in order.

1 - I enable the GCM service
[image]

2-I obtain an API key

1. click Create new key
2. click Server key. ( My IP not static IP, I use my server IP )

and my PHP code

```
function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
    $url        = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields     = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );
    // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "my-api-key");
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result == FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</h1>
<form method="post" action="index.php/?push=1">
    <div>
        <textarea rows="2" name="message" cols="23" placeholder="Message to transmit via GCM"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit"  value="Send Push Notification via GCM" /></div>
</form>
<p><h3><?php echo $pushStatus; ?></h3></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I get Unauthorized Error 401.
Please help.
Thank you.

My english little weak.
So sorry.